# Facebook Analytics: Is demographics information available without email ID?

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, facebook-analytics

Would facebook analytics provide demographic layer information if I integrate facebook sdk in my app without using facebook login and not reporting email ID associated with my app account?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you don't need to use FB login or upload PII to get demographic information.